# How to call a method in a class hierarchy?

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass, class-hierarchy

I have this super class which extends from another class

```
public abstract class AbstractDOEMessageFinderAction extends BasicObjectFinder {

    public Object performBasicSearch() {

        // works fine because getQuery is defined in BasicObjectFinder
        return getQuery(); 
    }
```

The other class is `ISIRFinderAction` which extends from `AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction`

```
ISIRFinderAction extends AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction {

    // My aim is to make sure this method works so that I will make
    // the super class's performBasicSearch() method abstract.

    public Object performBasicSearch() {

        // this one doesnt even compile but it extends AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction
        // which in turn extends BasicObjectFinder
        return getQuery();

    }

}
```

Am I missing something? Why is `getQuery` not working. I thought it would search it in the class hierarchy.

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: Aight. Now its formatted

Comment: Which is the compiler message when the compilation fails?

Comment: It looks like getQuery is not implemented anywhere? Is it abstract in BasicObjectFinder as well?

Comment: While you don't put `return` it won't compile.

Comment: getQuery() is implemented in BasicObjectFinder class. It is not abstract.
 The compile time error is "can't resolve method getQuery()."

Comment: @PeterMmm .. I edited my question again. The return is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second class extends `AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction` not `AbstractDOEMessageFinderAction`.

Comment: You are right, but when you use  getQuery(), shouldn't it get from the class hierarchy if it couldnt find it on super class it should go up one class and search there and so on.

Comment: I don't see the connection from `AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction` to `BasicObjectFinder` in your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Does `AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction` also extend `BasicObjectFinder`?

(Note, `AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction` is ofcourse not the same as `AbstractDOEMessageFinderAction`).

Comment: I am sorry. I edited it again. I wasn't copy pasting. That was the problem. There is no AbstractDOEMessageFinderAction. Instead it is AbstractDOEMessageDashboardAction